# Understanding multiprocessing in Julia

Tags: multiprocessing, julia

I am trying to understand multiprocessing in Julia and how to use it correctly.

I start Julia with 8 processes on my 20 core PC:

```
$ julia -p 8
```

With 8 processes running concurrently, I would expect a speedup of close to 8 times for embarrassingly parallel problems, at least for sufficiently long-running code to mitigate the added overhead from managing the multiple processes.

```
using BenchmarkTools
using Distributed
@everywhere using Random

@everywhere mt = MersenneTwister.(1:nworkers())

@everywhere function run_floats(N::Int64, m::Int64)
    sum = 0
    for i in 1:N
        sum += rand(mt[m])
    end
    return sum
end

function run_dist(N::Int64)
    sum = @distributed (+) for m=1:nworkers()
        run_floats(ceil(Int, N/nworkers()), m)
    end
    return sum
end
```

The above functions work as expected, resulting in a speedup of around 7, which gets closer to 8 for larger values of N,

```
julia> const N=10^8
100000000

julia> @btime run_floats(N,1);
  2.871 s (200000000 allocations: 2.98 GiB)

julia> @btime run_dist(N);
  391.685 ms (595 allocations: 26.83 KiB)
```

Now consider the slightly modified functions, where instead of random floats I'm adding up random arrays of single floats,

```
@everywhere function run_arrays(N::Int64, m::Int64)
    sum = zeros(1)
    for _ in 1:N
        sum += rand(mt[m],1)
    end
    return sum
end

function run_dist(N::Int64)
    sum = @distributed (+) for m=1:nworkers()
        run_arrays(ceil(Int, N/nworkers()), m)
    end
    return sum
end
```

In this case, the speedup is only around 4 (decreasing even further for larger arrays) and doesn't seem to improve for larger values of N,

```
julia> const N=10^8
100000000

julia> @btime run_arrays(N,1);
  5.512 s (200000001 allocations: 11.92 GiB)

julia> @btime run_dist(N);
  1.535 s (563 allocations: 27.03 KiB)
```

What is the reason behind the reduced effectiveness of multiprocessing in the above example? Does the CPU's cache become the bottleneck due to the arrays being harder to store? If so, is there a way I could measure this, or otherwise see if making use of multiprocessing would be sensible for a more complex problem?

Comment: I notice that the `run_arrays` allocates 4 times as much memory. When running with `Distributed`, the julia processes are independent. They will run the garbage collection when they reach some amount of memory use. Could it be that with many processes you run out of memory and end up with paging? (I see speedup of 7 for both cases, but I'm nowhere near exhausting my memory).

Comment: @SimenGaure your system has fast/many memory sticks and slow processor, his system has fast processor and slow/single memory stick, he's bottlenecked by the memory bandwidth... he should do algorithmic changes to get around that.

Comment: After enabling Intel XMP the speedup gets closer to 7 for arrays of length 1, so GC could indeed be the bottleneck. It's a pity that even for such a minimal example running multiple processes on one CPU in Julia becomes memory bound way before a significant fraction of the available cores get utilized.

Comment: Conserving memory is always a good idea, even more so in parallel applications. Your `rand(mt, 1)` allocates an array, likewise the `sum` is repeatedly assigned to a new array which is `sum + rand...`.  There is a `rand!` which you can use with a preallocated array. `tmp = zeros(1); rand!(mt, tmp); sum .+= tmp` to avoid many allocations. I.e. the `.+=` broadcasts and does not allocate a new array like `sum += ...` does.